# Flask partial view like MVC 3

Tags: python, flask

Is there something like .net MVC 3's partial view in flask?

I want to embed a widget in one view page,and that widget has its own logic.

Comment: You can write the widget code in a function, and call that function from a view, is that not enough?

Comment: @Alex Morega how to call the functin in jinja2 view template?

Comment: @magicshui You pass it into render_template as argument...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are several ways to include content in a Jinja2 template:

The [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include) statement will render the supplied view (with the current context by default):

```
{# In your_view_template.jinja #}
{# ... your code ... #}
{% include "widgets/your_widget.jinja" %}
{# ... your code ... #}
```

You can also define [macros](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros) and [import](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#import) them into the view template:

```
{# In your_view_template.jinja #}
{% import "widgets/your_widget.jinja" as your_widget %}
{# ... your code ... #}
{{ you_widget.render(your, important, variables, etc.) }}
{# ... your code ... #}
```

Both `import` and `include` can use variables, so something like this is possible:

```
# In your view
if complex_conditions.are_true():
    widget = "widgets/special_custom_widget.jinja"
else:
    widget = "widgets/boring_widget.jinja"
render_template("your_view.jinja", widget=widget)

{# In your_view_template.jinja #}
{% include widget %}
{# 
import widget as sidebar_widget 
{{ sidebar_widget.render() }}
would also work 
#}
```

These both work similarly to MVC's partial views (at least, inasmuch as I understand them)

Alternately, if your widget needs access to ACLs or information that should not be available to the template layer and you cannot re-write your view to take advantage of `include` and `import` you can take @[Alex Morega]'s suggestion and pass in a callable as a variable to the template and render it there.

```
# In your view
render_template("your_view.jinja", widget=you_callable, etc, etc, etc)

{# In your_view_template.jinja #}
{# ... your code ... #}
{{ widget() }}
{# Or, if you are returning HTML that is not a Markup construct #}
{{ widget() | safe }}
{# ... your code ... #}
```

You could **even** create your own [template loader](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#loaders) and load different templates depending on almost *anything*.  But that would definitely be overkill for this case.